# Linux - How to access/execute file from another folder and not changing folder

Tags: linux, bash

I tried multiple scenarios but these things are more of a headace. I tried writing this bash also for the same, but need to change in the same file which i need to execute. Can someone help me with the same.

```
#!/bin/bash -p
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "No arguments provided"
    exit 0
fi
CURRENT_DIR=`pwd`
EXEC_DIR=`dirname "$1"`
FILENAME="`basename $1`"
cd $EXEC_DIR
CMD="./$FILENAME ${@:2}"
$CMD
cd $CURRENT_DIR
```

i need some two liner to work with the same file which i need to execute.

Comment: Use a *sub-shell* to change the directory and execute the program? Something like `(cd $EXEC_DIR; ./$FILENAME ${@:2})`? That will cause the sub-shell to execute the program in the new directory, but your script will still continue without changing directory.

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate on the problems you have with the script you show? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Unclear, Why not simply `"$1" ${@:2}` to execute the file presumably if an absolute path was passed along with the filename. If you don't want to permanently change to `EXEC_DIR` you can always use `pushd` and `popd` (in the same way you would use `cd` but without the return directory needing specification.

Comment: I know directly giving a path can execute the script from any folder. But if there is reference of another local file within ( . <filename> ) how will that be resolved. I have some other local dependencies in the script resolved via '.' current directory.Also i got the solution: i have to change the mail fail itself rather than writing this script.


EXEC_DIR=`dirname "$0"`
cd $EXEC_DIR

Answer (score 0):

If your script is present in /opt/ and you are in /opt/dir/ then you can run the script from there only like this --> ../script.sh it will run the script from previous folder and run it in present folder

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the full path of the file/script you want to execute :

```
/path/to/file/example.bash
```

You will stay in your current directory, but your script `example.bash` will be executed.

Comment: Think before answering .. I know directly giving a path can execute the script from any folder. But if there is reference of another local file within ( . <filename> ) how will that be resolved. I have some other local dependencies in the script resolved via '.' current directory.

also i have got the answer. i need to change the script itself rather than writing a new script. 

EXEC_DIR=`dirname "$0"`
cd $EXEC_DIR